# Wrapping a function with an indeterminate number of parameters in F#

Tags: f#, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to write a simple wrapper class in F# that takes a function that returns a string, and returns a function that takes the same parameters and returns the string from the input 'wrapped'.

The following code works for functions that take a single variable (so `test` works fine):

```
open System

let myFunc anotherFunc =
    fun x -> "boo" + anotherFunc x + "unboo"

let Func2 toDouble =
    (toDouble * 2).ToString ()

let test = myFunc Func2

let Func3 numOne numTwo =
    (numOne * numTwo).ToString ()

let test2 = myFunc Func3

do
    Console.WriteLine(test 10)
    Console.WriteLine(test2 5 10)
```

But because `fun x ->` specifies a single parameter, `test2` is not valid code. Is there a piece of syntax that would allow for this construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function works.
The problem is in your last line when you do

```
let test2 = myFunc Func3
```

should be

```
let test2 x = myFunc (Func3 x)
```

UPDATE:

I'm assuming you don't want to change Func3. Otherwise the solution from Tomas could be what you need.

Comment: This will work too, but it does a bit different thing than when wrapping a function that takes just a single parameter (or a tuple). In your version, the `myFunc` function is executed each time you call `test2`, while in the single-parameter version, the `myFunc` function gets called just once. In this case, it doesn't really matter, but if the `myFunc` actually did something, then it might be a problem - i.e. it might be inefficient or it might not work if `myFunc` used some internal mutable state.

Comment: Of course, it depends on your assumption. I don't have the full source code, so I assumed you can't change Func3.

Comment: I'll bare the warning in mind. `myFunc` will be a fairly lightweight pure function; the performance hit is less of an issue to me than the ability to easily curry functions returned by `myFunc` so Gustavo's solution suits my use case better.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to write `Func3` as a function that takes a tuple. This way, the function will take just a single parameter, but you can pass it both of the numbers:

```
// Function takeing a single argument, which is a tuple
let Func3 (numOne, numTwo) = 
  (numOne * numTwo).ToString () 

let test2 = myFunc Func3      

// The created function takes a tuple as well
Console.WriteLine(test2(5, 10))
```

In general, there is no good way to write a higher-order function that takes a function accepting any number of parameters. This kind of genericity cannot be easily encoded in F#. You could use Reflection to build something like that (but that would be inefficient and unsafe), or you could write some more complex encoding of parameters, but I think that tuple is the best option.