# Running a function with recursion F#

Tags: f#

I am doing something really basic wrong, but I can't, for the life of me, work out what it is...

```
    let rec testItSeveralTimes (test, times) =
        printfn "Iterations to go %O" times
        match times with
            | 0 -> ()
            | _ -> 
                test
                testItSeveralTimes (test, (times - 1))

     testItSeveralTimes ((printfn "Running a test"), 2)
```

What I expect is:

```
Iterations to go 2
Running a test
Iterations to go 1
Running a test
Iterations to go 0
Running a test
val it : unit = ()
```

What I get is:

```
Running a test
Iterations to go 2
Iterations to go 1
Iterations to go 0
val it : unit = ()
```

It seems like the function is being evaluated once, at the beginning, and then ignored.

This question ([Wrapping a function with an indeterminate number of parameters in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379254/wrapping-a-function-with-an-indeterminate-number-of-parameters-in-f)) seemed to have an answer, but no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you extract out the `test` parameter into a separate step,
the problem becomes obvious:

```
let test = printfn "Running a test"
// expression has run and printed already!
// value of "test" is a simple value (unit) now
testItSeveralTimes (test, 2)
```

As part of evaluating the `let test =` expression, the `printfn`
function is run *immediately*.

Then, `test` is assigned the value `()`, which is the output of `printfn`

Inside `testItSeveralTimes`, the value of test is just there, but doesn't
do anything.

As John said, you need to make the `test` parameter be a function that can be run:

```
let rec testItSeveralTimes (test, times) =
    printfn "Iterations to go %O" times
    match times with
        | 0 -> ()
        | _ -> 
            test()  // test parameter is now a function
            testItSeveralTimes (test, (times - 1))
```

With this change, you also need to define the `test` value as a function that
is not run immediately:

```
let test() = printfn "Running a test"
// value of test is a function and is not run yet
testItSeveralTimes (test, 2)
```

As a general rule, if you are having problems understanding what is going, try breaking out all the steps into separate values like this -- it makes it easier to debug, because you can evaluate each one in turn (in F# Interactive or REPL) and see what happens!

Answer (score 2):

Here test has a value of `unit`.

You want something like

```
testItSeveralTimes ((fun _ -> printfn "Running a test"), 2)
```

and change the usage to

```
test()
```

Comment: I changed it to this:

        let rec testItSeveralTimes (test, times) =
            printfn "Iterations to go %O" times
            match times with
                | 0 -> ()
                | _ -> 
                    test()
                    testItSeveralTimes (test, (times - 1))

        testItSeveralTimes ((fun _ -> printfn "Running a test"), 2)

And it works, but I am not sure why.  Is it because test() forces it to be evaluated as a function?